# How to specify the application config file in a Wix Custom Action that will execute an exe that is in a Binary element?

Tags: custom-action, wix3.5

I have an .Net 6 exe that is published as a single exe with its app config along side it.  I want to run this exe after the commit stage of the wix installation.  I know that the exe can be embedded in the msi using the Binary element and specifying a custom action to run this exe.  What I don't know is how do a specify the app config of this exe?  Does anyone know how to do this?